# Custom Auto-Sort Macro Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to customize the below macro. What I would like the macro to do is auto-sort as per the below list. Any suggestions on how I could go about doing this?

Thank you.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A7").Sort Key1:=Range("A8:A18"), _
          Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
          MatchCase:=False, _
          Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

End If
End Sub
```

Preferred sorting structure:

- Best Choices
- Use Caution
- Not Recommended

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you entirely, but couldn't you make a hidden column with formulas that reference the text cells and transform "Best Choices" to 1, "Use Caution" to 2, and "Not Recommended" to 3? Then you could just sort on the hidden column.

Comment: Hi rdhs, thank you for your response. I guess I'm providing a very succinct version of what I'm doing. I have a master sheet, in which based on input and using VLOOKUP, either "Best Choices", "Use Caution", and "Not Recommended" are returned. Then what I would like that master sheet to do is organize the list, to return "Best Choices" at the top of the list. So I'm not entirely sure if I can include a hidden column there. If you believe it is possible, could you advise how I should go about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Since you are forced to use those values in your sort, the code below should perform a custom sort (Just change the dataCell value to where your data is):

```
Sub sortData()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim rSort As Range
Dim rKey As Range
Dim customSort(1 To 3) As String
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

dataCell = "A7" ' Change this to the top left-hand cell in your dataset

Set rSort = sh1.Range(dataCell).CurrentRegion
Set rKey = sh1.Range(dataCell)

customSort(1) = "Best Choice"
customSort(2) = "Use Caution"
customSort(3) = "Not Recommended"

Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=customSort
rSort.Sort Key1:=rKey, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1, MatchCase:=False, _
Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi stobin, Thank you. I completely agree with you. Problem is, that's the terminology my coworkers wish to use. I've seen somewhere where you can actually specify which words and in which order you would like to sort them within a macro. I just can't seem to find that info though.

Comment: ahh I understand. I modified my code so that you can specify the words to sort by. This should do the trick.